# tensorflow trace doesn't work

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow. I have a tensor x as follows:

```
>>> x.eval()
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)
```

I want to calculate trace of this tensor, so I use [tf.trace](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#trace), but it throws the error:

```
>>> tf.trace(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'trace'
```

How can I fix it? Many thanks

Comment: Interesting. Looks like a bug in tensorflow.

Comment: @etarion yep, the error is because the old version. I re-install and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]], dtype=tf.int32)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x.eval()
tf.trace(x).eval()
```

this prints

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
15
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. Maybe I'm using an old version? But I installed just one month ago.

Comment: 1 month old is ancient

Comment: After re-installing, it works fine,so it's the problem of old version.